# ArrayList выдает значение null

Tags: java, массивы, list, arraylist

У меня ArrayList выдает значение null. В чем может быть проблем?

```
static ArrayList<Customer> user = new ArrayList<>();

    public void users () {
        CustomerLoyal customerLoyal1 = new CustomerLoyal("Nastya", "Moskovskaya", "username1", "", "+372114114");
        CustomerLoyal customerLoyal2 = new CustomerLoyal("Semyon", "Sokolov", "username2", "", "+372114115");

        user.add(customerLoyal1);
        user.add(customerLoyal2);
    }
    
    public void printUsers() {
        for (int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(user.get(i).getFirstName() + " " + user.get(i).getLastName() + ", Username: " + user.get(i).getUserName());
        }
    }
```

Здесь вызывается метод `printUsers()`

```
  case 7:
     System.out.println("Choose client: ");
     clients.printUsers();
     break;
```

Наверное будет уместо показать сам CustomerLoyal

```
public class CustomerLoyal extends Customer{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public CustomerLoyal(){}

    public CustomerLoyal(String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String password, String phoneNumber) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: "проблем" в том, что мы не понимаем, что значит эта фраза - "У меня ArrayList выдает значение null.". Где выдает, куда выдает? Что должен "выдать"?

Comment: В качестве подсказки: в объекте `CustomerLoyal` два поля с именем `firstName`,  например. Заполняете вы одно поле, а печатаете другое.

Comment: Не надо минусить. Вопрос задан кривовато, но касается тонкого места в `Java`: поля не виртуальны и перекрываются в потомках без предупреждения. Такой код можно отлаживать довольно долго не понимать что одно и то же имя ссылается на разные поля в предке и потомке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример того что у вас в коде происходит. Предок и наследник объявляют два поля с одним и тем же именем `f`. Код предка работает со своим полем, наследник - со своим. Поля не виртуальны в отличие от методов:

```
public class HideField {
    public static class A {
        public String f = "A::f";
        public String getF() {
            return f;
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        public String f = null;
        public void setF(String s) {
            f = s;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.setF("B::f");
        System.out.println(b.f);
        System.out.println(b.getF());
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac HideField.java && java HideField 
> B::f
> A::f
> ```

Чтобы исправить ситуацию, не создавайте поле в потомке ещё раз:

```
public class HideField {
    public static class A {
        public String f = "A::f";
        public String getF() {
            return f;
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        // public String f = null;
        public void setF(String s) {
            f = s;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.setF("B::f");
        System.out.println(b.f);
        System.out.println(b.getF());
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac HideField.java && java HideField 
> B::f
> B::f
> ```